# Query worksheet using column range

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to query an excel worksheet using ADODB. The problem is there are many columns with a similar name and I'm unable to select the correct column in my query. Is there a was to select the column by using its range? Something like

```
select [A:A],[AB:AB] from [Sheet1$]
```

The source worksheet kind of looks like this

```
     A      B      C      D     E     F     G      H     I
1                  08/19/2013         08/18/2013         08/17/2013
2  Col1   Col2    col3   col4  col5   col3  col4   col5  col3
3
```

When I try to import all the data I get all the data minus the column names, only `col1` and `col2` are fetched. Its the same when I do `from [Sheet1$]` and `from [Sheet1$A2:K100]`

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple columns with the same or similar names, Excel/ODBC will probably do some funky name-mangling to make sure they are different in the recordset. What I would do is get all the columns with "SELECT *" then examine the fields names in the result set - then you can go back and retrieve by name just the columns you want.

Comment: Its doing something funky alright. Its not printing the column names.

Comment: What is your client? Almost any client will allow you to read the field names. Are you saying the names of the fields in the resulting recordset are all blank?

Comment: I've added some extra information, hope this helps and yes that is what it looks like.